# Where to upload files for subdomain over kloxo?

Tags: subdomain, hosting, vps, server, kloxo

I have added a subdomain in my kloxo vps but after i uploaded my files in the generated directory the kloxo default page didnt change ,  i have restarted the apache but the problem still not solved.

Subdomain Directory:
/home/admin/files

Subdomain:
http://files.84050.ir/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your directory isn't right. From what I've been told you need this, "/home/kloxo/httpd/default/" to change your default page.

Comment: I dont want to change the default page , i dont want to see the default page in my subdomain because i have uploaded my own page

Comment: I see, hmm, I'm interested to know how that's done too.